# Creating initializer for Core Data objects

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and writing a little test app.  What I'm trying to do is have a  object that I can save into a sqlite database.

My properties look like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * street;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * zip;
```

These are all @dynamic in the .m file.

I originally did this:

```
+ (AddressAnnotation *)initWithPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    AddressAnnotation *anAddress = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressAnnotation" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    anAddress.address = placemark.subThoroughfare;
    anAddress.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
    anAddress.city = placemark.locality;
    ....
    return anAddress;
}
```

However, I did not know how to override

```
- (NSString *)title;
- (NSString *)subtitle;
```

for the  protocol so my callout gets shown.  One of them looks like:

```
- (NSString *)title {
    if (self.name) {
        return self.name;
    }
    else {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Subtitle is pretty similar but with other properties.  However, this doesn't work since these are for instances and not for a class object right?

So I changed my initializer to look like:

```
- (AddressAnnotation *)initWithPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    AddressAnnotation *anAddress = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressAnnotation" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSLog(@"placemark: %@", [placemark description]);
    anAddress.address = placemark.subThoroughfare;
    anAddress.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
    ...

    return anAddress;
}
```

However when I do this, all my values are null.  What is the proper way to write an initializer in this situation?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first `+initWithPlacemark` looks correct, except for the name. `initWith…` methods are pretty much reserved for instance "constructors". Use something like `+insertNewAddressAnnotationWithPlacemark:` or a shorter `+newWithPlacemark:` method name. `-initWithPlacemark:` is definitely a bad idea.

Your implementation for `-title` seems adequate, but I do not understand what you mean when you tell if doesn't work and the rest after.

If you want to have specific default values for your properties, you can use the model default value field. `-awakeFromInsert` is another way to set default values, per example for transformable attributes or computed default values. A `+insertNewWith…` class method is a perfect way to create, insert and initialize a new instance with specific values.

Comment: The part that seemed funny to me was When I use the + class method to create my object, when the viewForAnnotation: method gets called when I place the pin on the map, the callout gets shown.  When I use the - instance method, the callout does not get shown since the .name value is null.  Thoughts?  Thanks!